# GCC > 7 on Ubuntu 18.04, expected to work?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, libstdc++

I want to understand what's happening under the hood when using a newer GCC than the "default" version for a given version of Ubuntu.

1. Starting with a plain Ubuntu 18.04, I have:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25
```

2. Then I install gcc-11 (via the toolchains/test ppa repo) and I get:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/libstdc++.so
```

I also notice that the system-provided version gets overriden!

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.29
```

3. I can compile a hello-world application with `g++-11`, and get the following via `ldd`:

```
ldd a.out 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc79ff7000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fd378546000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd378155000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd377db7000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd378b55000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fd377b9f000)
```

So it's linking to the system-installed version of `libstdc++`, instead of the compiler-provided version. The binary runs just fine.

My questions are:

- Is this expected to work or I'm just lucky with my tiny example? What can possibly go wrong?
- Why is the system-provided library overriden? With what?
- If there's a build of GCC-11 for Ubuntu 18.04, does it mean it's guaranteed to work in Ubuntu 18.04?
- In what way do the two libstdc++ libraries (system-provided and gcc-11-provided) differ?
- What about other libraries, like libgcc_s.so? The same happens, there's the "system" provided one, and the "GCC-provided" one.
- Do I need to worry about the remaining libs that are present in ldd? (libc, libm, linux-vsdo). It seems there's only one version in the system, but I wonder if they get overriden when installing GCC.

Thanks!

Comment: Briefly, the key is that both libstdc++ have major version 6, so they are expected to be binary-compatible.  The libstdc++ from gcc-11 must provide all the same functions as the one from the system gcc, and they must behave identically (other than bug fixes).  Thus the new libstdc++ is supposed to be a drop-in replacement for the old one.

Comment: If the new libstdc++ were not compatible, it would have bumped the version number to `libstdc++.so.7`, and then it would only get used by programs compiled and linked by the new gcc - existing programs would continue to use the existing library.

Comment: You might be getting lucky, but the writers and maintainers of Standard Library implementations generally go out of their way to allow you to get lucky. You may find that some functionality added in C++17 and 20 do not exist.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475/how-do-so-shared-object-numbers-work is good background reading.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies! One issue I ran into (not in this example) is building something on Ubuntu 20 (GCC 9) and running on Ubuntu 18 (GCC 7). It complained about "GLIBC symbol not found". Is this a separate issue? I.e. can I get "symbol not found" when using different libstdc++ versions, or am I safe in that regard (as long as I build and run on the same Ubuntu version)?

Comment: Like, for example, there's `libc.so.6`, but it seems they are not compatible between Ubuntu 20 and 18 even though they have the same major version (?) So I wonder if the same problem can arise with `libstdc++` and others (`libgcc_s`)

Comment: The libraries are backwards compatible but there is no guarantee they are forward compatible. If you build something with the newer library and end up using one of the symbols introduced in the new version, you will find the old version did not have that symbol and you will get a "symbol not found" error. Predicting the future is really really hard.

Comment: A new system adds new features not present on an old system, but tries not to remove old features or change them in incompatible ways. Thus, old programs generally run on new systems, but new programs do not generally run on old systems, because new programs use new features.

Comment: I see, thanks. That makes sense. So by "new features" do you mean e.g. to use C++20 features with GCC-11? If I restrict myself to e.g. C++14, which is also fully supported in GCC-7, does that sound like a safe option? The reason for using GCC-11 would be bug fixes, better optimization and diagnostics.

Comment: I also see the following here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html

> Binaries with equivalent DT_SONAMEs are forward-compatibile

The SONAME is always libstdc++.so.6, and they don't explicitly list incompatibilities between GCC 7 and 11, so is this a guarantee that GCC 7's libstdc++ is forward-compatible with GCC 11's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the great info I got from the comments, I think I got a good enough understanding to answer the question. Thanks everyone!

- If the `libstdc++` has the same major version (the one in the SONAME), then they are **backwards-compatible**. Meaning that something built on a older `libstdc++` is guaranteed to run on a newer `libstdc++`.
- The opposite is not true in general - the library is **not forward-compatible**. If a new symbol is introduced in a new library, it naturally doesn't exist in the older library. This can be reproduced as follows:

  - Start on Ubuntu 20.04.
  - Copy the example code from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator).
  - Compile it with the default GCC 9 and `-std=c++17`.
  - This binary runs fine on Ubuntu 20.04.
  - Now, copy that binary over to a stock Ubuntu 18.04.
  - You'll get a "symbol not found error":

    ```
    ./a.out: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by ./a.out)
    ```

- When you install a new GCC on Ubuntu, it will **override** the system-wide libstdc++ (possibly other libs?) with the GCC-provided `libstdc++` (so they are identical). This will ensure that whatever you build on that machine will also run there.